# Diagrama Box Plot en Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Necesito crear un gráfica Box plot (Diagrama de caja bigotes) en Chart.js pero no logro encontrar la manera de realizarlo con la biblioteca descrita.

Comment: Existen addons de Chart.js para crear Box plots: https://github.com/datavisyn/chartjs-chart-box-and-violin-plot

Comment: si no encuentras en Chart.js , siempre puedes tener una alternativa con google chart , toma un [ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/48ynpzd0/)